# Which community to post a question about finding a FOSS product

Tags: discussion, site-recommendation

I am a Stack Overflow community member looking for an interactive end-user reporting generator that can process XML files. Where do I ask that question?

Answer (score 7):

I think you should investigate [Software Recommendations](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic):

> This site is for questions asking for recommendations of software to
>   accomplish a particular task, that is, “what software can I use to do
>   …?”. Note that recommendations of tutorials, data sources, etc. are
>   off-topic.

Be sure to read its [question quality guidelines](https://softwarerecs.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/336/what-is-required-for-a-question-to-contain-enough-information) before posting.

Answer (score 5):

[Software Recommendations](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/) SE should be the perfect choice for this question.

They also have tags named [opensource](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/open-source) for the exact same purpose. So, in order to ask a nice question on the SoftwareRecs, you have to keep in mind the following:

- Be clear about the things you want from the software (the specifications)
- Mention the platforms (like the OS, etc) which you are using (the compatibility)
- Be as precise and clear as possible about the desired requirements and the details.